# Copy data PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I can not copy data between a file and a data PostgresSQL

I have txt file

```
08.10.2020|pqgpardaql|куфожйэюхю|81720836|6,12517552|
11.03.2020|otsevjoqbe|ппыыдвпцёе|84094422|5,61357632|
06.05.2018|modjmucfmq|ювэючхптдв|64162072|19,81894589|
```

I have query

```
"COPY test FROM 'D:\\test\\unionFile.txt' DELIMITER '|'";
```

but i get error

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 1: "08.10.2020|pqgpardaql|куфожйэюхю|81720836|6,12517552|"
```

How can i go to the next line while copying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the pipe symbol in the last of every line

08.10.2020|pqgpardaql|куфожйэюхю|81720836|6,12517552
11.03.2020|otsevjoqbe|ппыыдвпцёе|84094422|5,61357632
06.05.2018|modjmucfmq|ювэючхптдв|64162072|19,81894589

i imported with this command

```
COPY test FROM 'D:\\test\\unionFile.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));
```

**IT worked**